# float:none; not working with media queries

Tags: html, css, css-float, media-queries

I'm following a tutorial about responsive design and when trying to set the `float` property to `none` for a media query targeting `(max-width: 625px)` for a section having a class `main` as in the following rule-sets :

```
/* Section main */

section.main {
    background-color: blue;
    width: :100%;
    float: none;
    text-align: left;
}

section.main aside div.content {
    background-color: green;
    margin: 8px 20px 8px 0;
    padding: 5px 0px 10px 85px;
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    background-position: 20px 5px;
}
```

Here is the full html and css code all together: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ry8w95za/) (I added colors of blue to the `section.main` and the green color to the `section.main aside div.content` in these same media query rule-sets to make sure they do have effect on the html and to make it easy to be located in the page.

These three green `div`s are supposed to be stacked vertically when the float is set to none.

Comment: you have a typo on line # 377. Remove extra `:` from `width: :100%;` I hope it will fix your problem.

Comment: why do you need to make it `float: none;` when it's not yet been floated?

Comment: @Muhammad Usman thanks , i fixed the typo but the float problem remains

Comment: @Ron Basco thanks too , your comment makes me find the reason why it didn't work! the float is applied to the section.main aside and not to its parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ry8w95za/1/) i've edited your fiddle and came up with this. hope this sample helps.

```
section.main aside {
      float: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    }
    section.main aside div.content {
        background-color: green;
        margin: 8px 20px 8px 20px;
        padding:20px 15px;
    text-align: center;
        background-size: 50px 50px;
        background-position: 20px 5px;
    }
```